# Two form on a single page : How to identify which form validate using jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a html page which contains

1. a form with fields for sign up (registration / new member)
2. a form for sign in (login for already member)

The sign in form is :

```
<form class="dialog-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>PAssword</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="My PAssword" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="sign_in" value="Connexion" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The sign up form is :

```
   <form class="dialog-form" action="bat/user_validation.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="My secret password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Type your password again" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="sign_up" value="Inscription" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

One the other side, I have a php script file which contains function to check and insert a userid.

```
    function getPassword($utilisateur) {
        try {
        $dbh = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);
        $uid = $utilisateur;
        $sql = "SELECT password FROM cc_users WHERE uid =:uid";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':uid'=>$uid));
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
            return (count($result) == 1) ;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Erreur ! : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }   
    }

    function setPassword($uid, $pass) {
        $dbh = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);
        $sql = "UPDATE cc_users SET password =:pass where uid =:uid";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':pass'=>$pass ,':uid'=>$uid));
        echo $count = $sth->rowCount();
        return $dbh->exec($sql);
    }

    function newPassword($utilisateur, $pass) {
        $crypt = crypt($pass);
        return setPassword($utilisateur, $crypt);
    }

    function checkPassword($utilisateur, $pass) {
        if (empty($pass)) return FALSE;
        $interne = getPassword($utilisateur);
        $crypt = crypt($pass, $interne);
        return ($interne === $crypt);
    }
print_r($_POST);
```

My questions are : 
How I can check on which form the user is coming?
How can I do an $.ajax call for checking the form? If yes how?
Thanks

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
Form 1:
<form id="form1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
Form 2:
<form id="form2">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); // Logs the id of the submitted form
});
```

Comment: I am struggling with the problem. I have now one form and use this to submit my form with jquery.`$( "#signup" ).submit(function( event ) {
          var $form = $( this ), url = $form.attr( "action" );
         console.log($form.serialize() );
          var posting = $.post( url, { s: $form.serialize() } );
          posting.done(function( data ) {
            $( "#register-dialog" ).append( data );
          });
        });` my php script return echo 'ok'. What i want is to have ok in my data object when the posting is done. where am wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Give name for `<form>`

```
<form class="dialog-form" name="signin">

<form class="dialog-form" action="bat/user_validation.php" method="post" name="signup">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check `$_POST` global to see if it contains the name of your `<input type="submit" />`. It will contain either `sign_up` or `sign_in`, depending on what button did the user press.

For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['sign_up']){
    $signingUp = true;
}
```

If you want to submit the form using jQuery ajax, you can use the following code snippet:

```
$.post('bat/user_validation.php', $('form.dialog-form').serialize());
```

Though the selector should be more concrete, probably including a form ID to distinguish between the two forms.